# Copy data from one table to another table in a before edit action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I am building a versioning model and am trying to make a copy of a previous version

Post.rb

```
  has_many :versions, class_name: "PostVersion",  foreign_key: "post_id", dependent: :destroy

before_update :create_version

private

  def create_version
    PostVersion.create!(title: self.title, body: self.body...[redacted because there is a lot of data...you get the idea])
  end
```

PostVersion.rb

```
belongs_to :original_post, class_name: "PostVersion",  foreign_key: "post_id"
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this where I don't list out each column?  I am using postgres & Rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **all** the *attribute identifiers* are the same and you're simply copying over, try the following:

```
private

  def create_version
    # Modify the keys in except call to filter out additional attrs
    PostVersion.create!(self.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at"))
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use [`paper_trail`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#features) gem.

Examples from its documentation:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end

widget = Widget.find 153
widget.name                                 # 'Doobly'
widget.versions                             # []
widget.update_attributes :name => 'Wotsit'
widget.versions.last.reify.name             # 'Doobly'
widget.versions.last.event                  # 'update'
widget.versions.last.whodunnit              # '153'  (if the update was via a controller and
                                            #         the controller has a current_user method,
                                            #         here returning the id of the current user)
```